# Implement a function that fetches bit from byte array

Tags: arrays, c, sum, fetch, byte

I do not have much expertise in bit operation as I am beginner. Can you help me or give me any clue! how to do this in C programming!-
This function fetches bits from a byte array, which contains suitable number of bytes to cover the largest bit index in  bit_idxs array. It assumes that the bytes in the array are
composed as follows:

- if array = {0xA3, 0x58}, it assumes a number 0xA358 = 1010 0011 0101 1000, and assigns bit index 0 as the left most bit.
  if bit_idxs = {0, 2, 10} and n = 3, it fetch 1010 0011 0101 1000
  ^ ^         ^
  1, 1, 0 since bit 0 is 1, bit 2 is 1, and bit 10 is 0. Then, it sums these bit values, which is 2. Before returning the sum,it clears the bits that are set, that is, it clears bit 0 and bit 2
  so that the array becomes
  0000 0011 0101 1000
  ^ ^         ^
  array = {0x03, 0x58}.

Comment: So you need to take the index, and calculate from it two other indices - one, is for the byte within the array which is containing the bit, and the other one is for the bit number within this byte. Can you do that?

Comment: Hint: just do 1 bit at a time. If bit_idx = {0, 2, 10} then you can do bit_idx=0, bit_idx=2, and bit_idx=10, each separately.

Comment: What bit ordering do you want? Assume we're using `unsigned char`. Do you want: `00  01  02  03  04  05  06  07 | 08  09  10  11  12  13  14  15` The code is: `void bset(unsigned char *bvec,int bitno) { bvec[bitno >> 3] |= 0x80 >> (bitno & 0x07); }  unsigned char bget(const unsigned char *bvec,int bitno) { return bvec[bitno >> 3] & (0x80 >> (bitno & 0x07)); }`

Comment: Or, `07  06  05  04  03  02  01  00 | 15  14  13  12  11  10  09  08` And, the code is: `void bset(unsigned char *bvec,int bitno) { bvec[bitno >> 3] |= 1 << (bitno & 0x03); }  unsigned char bget(const unsigned char *bvec,int bitno) { return bvec[bitno >> 3] & (1 << (bitno & 0x03)); }`

Comment: I do not understand bit operation that much. for example I have array B={0xAf, 0x58,0x87} and bitindexarray = {0,7}. i should get the sum of bit with 0 and 7 index and clear that. But I dont know how to approach logically

Comment: @EugeneSh. No. I am unable to imply the logic. can u explain a bit more!